# Centos 6 stuck at loading splash screen after successful installation

Tags: centos, system-installation

I'm trying to dual-boot CentOS with Windows 7.

My current disk layout are as follow:-

```
/dev/sda1 - Windows 7
/dev/sda3 - NTFS partition
```

I created a standard partition for `/boot` and that was assigned as `/dev/sda2`.

When I create LVM Physical Volume, it automatically creates an **Extended Partition** (`/dev/sda4`) and the LVM Physical Volume (`/dev/sda5`) was created under the Extended Partition.

I then created 2 volume group for `/` and `swap`.

Upon complete installation, I'm unable to login to Centos at all. It is stuck at the loading splash screen.

Does this have anything to do with the disk layout? If so, how can I fix this?

EDITED

Instead of dual-booting it, I installed it as a VM on my Windows Machine. I started off with a blank disk layout, create /boot partition followed by the LVM Physical Volume. It installed fine and was able to boot up normally. I presume the issue was due to the LVM Physical Volume sitting in the Extended Partition that ruined the boot-up. Could be wrong through. Should I mount the extended partition first or something?

Comment: During the booting, press the down arrow key. It will show you the boot log and you will see what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can try. For starters I'd try and boot a Live Distro or use the Rescue Disc facility that comes with CentOS to make sure you can mount your /boot and / partitions.

Assuming they're mountable I'd take a look at your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file and make sure that it's referencing the correct HDD partitions for your / partition.

#### For example

```
title CentOS (2.6.32-220.el6.i686)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.i686 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_centos62-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_centos62/
lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_centos62/lv_root rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb 
crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.i686.img
```

Make sure that the `root ...` line in your menu.lst file is referencing the correct partition.

This [Techotopia Dual Boot Howto](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_CentOS_6_with_Windows_in_a_Dual_Boot_Environment) may be helpful as well.

#### Extended Partitions

If you take a look at this [CentOS forum post](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=38813) they show a fairly involved setup with multiple OSes all on a single HDD. The OP at the bottom seems to be having the same conclusion you are, mainly:

> However, I CAN manually chain Windows Vista (hd1, 0) and Solaris x/86
>   (hd0, 3), which makes me wonder: Is it something about the two
>   CentOSes being in LVMs that I am not accounting for in my grub
>   records? As it stands, I will manually have to swap the boot order
>   from the BIOS if I want to go between CentOS5 and CentOS6...

Comment: Hi @slm, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the disk layout. Instead of dual-booting, I installed it as a VM on my Windows machine and start with an empty disk layout. Everything was fine and I'm able to boot. I presume that this might be due to the Physical Volume in Extended Partition somewhat ruined the bootup.

Comment: If you think it's a disk partitioning issue then you can manually select how to do the partitioning during the CentOS installation. I'd make it so that it doesn't make use of Logical Volume Mgmt. when setting up the / partition.